# Как вывести данные аккаунта (номер аккаунта, баланс и т.д) вместо хэша Model.BankAccount@2d98a335

Tags: java, arraylist

Необходимо вывести данные об аккаунте в методе `wyswietlListe`.

```
public class Bank implements BankingOperations, Observable {

    private BankAccount bankAccount;
    private ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts;
    private List<ObserverOffice> observerOffices = new ArrayList<>();

    public Bank() {
        accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    }

    public boolean hasAccount(BankAccount account) {
        for (BankAccount ba : accounts) {
            if (ba.getNrAccount() == account.getNrAccount()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Stream API: anyMatch
    public boolean hasAccountStream(BankAccount account) {
        return accounts.stream().anyMatch(ba -> ba.getNrAccount() == account.getNrAccount());
    }

    public void addAccount(BankAccount e) throws NrAccountEX {
        if (hasAccount(e)) {
            throw new NrAccountEX("Account z takim id juz istieje");
        }
        accounts.add(e);
        System.out.println("Konto: " + e + " Zostało dodane!");
    }
    
    public void wyswietlListe() {
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(accounts.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(accounts);
    }

    @Override
    public void deposit(int nrAccount, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
                if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccount)) {
                    accounts.get(i).deposit(amount);
                    System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                    if (amount >= 10000) {
                        //+raport
                        notifyObserverOffice(accounts.get(i), amount);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void withdraw(int nrAccount, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
                if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccount)) {
                    if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() < amount) {
                        throw new NoMoneyEX("Twój balance " + accounts.get(i).getBalance() + "jest mniejszy od kwoty" + amount + "Podaj mniejszą kwotę");
                    } else if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() >= amount) {
                        accounts.get(i).withdraw(amount);
                        System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało obciazone o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                    }
                    if (amount >= 10000) {
                        //+raport
                        notifyObserverOffice(accounts.get(i), amount);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void transfer(int nrAccountFrom, int nrAccountTO, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
                if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccountFrom) == true) {
                    if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() < amount) {
                        throw new NoMoneyEX("Saldo twojego konta nie pozwala zrobic przelew: balance " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                    } else if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() >= amount) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < accounts.size(); j++) {
                            if (accounts.get(j).equals(nrAccountTO)) {
                                accounts.get(i).withdraw(amount);
                                accounts.get(j).deposit(amount);
                                System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccountFrom + " zostało obciazone o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                                System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccountTO + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                                if (amount >= 10000) {
                                    //raport
                                    notifyObserverOffice(accounts.get(i), amount);
                                }
                            } else {
                                throw new NrAccountEX("Konto na kture chcesz zrobic przelew nie istnieje, podaj prawidlowy numer");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new NrAccountEX("Konto z kturego chcesz zrobic przelew nie istnieje, podaj prawidlowy numer");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addObserverOffice(ObserverOffice observerOffice) {
        observerOffices.add(observerOffice);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteObserverOffice(ObserverOffice observerOffice) {
        observerOffices.remove(observerOffice);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObserverOffice(BankAccount bankAccount, double amount) {
        // for each
        for (ObserverOffice ob : observerOffices) {
            ob.updateObserverOffice(bankAccount, amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переопределите метод `toString` в классе `BankAccount`.

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BankAccount{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", balance=" + balance +
                ", owner='" + owner + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```